# Atomic transactions with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MEAN stack. please help with this situation.

My function has to do this and i want to make this threadsafe, i.e. i wanted to use this inside an API

1) query a collection and get a field from a document, say version.

2) Delete another document that matches with this version and other fields, in another DB.

3) insert new document in collection with new data, and version = version + 1

This would've been pretty simple in C# + Sql server world.

What is the best way to achieve this in node + mongodb environment?

Comment: All of these operations are atomic on document level. Since you are new to MEAN stak, may I ask you to confirm terminology. Do you really want to delete a **collection**, then insert new **collection**? Collection in mongo is something similar to tables in SQL.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for correction, i meant document. Edited the question.

Comment: While it is possible to operate on multiple databases in MongoDB,  it is generally not a good *starting point* and I suspect you do not really need to do that. I suggest you go back to your requirements and architect a MongoDB solution from functional requirements rather than trying to mechanically translate SQL.

Comment: If the databases are within the same server you can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/. I think MSSQL has the same limitation for cross-database transactions. Mongo transactions are not that mature as SQL ones tho. Worth reading if you roll it out to prod in the nearest future https://jepsen.io/analyses/mongodb-4.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB [does not allow DDL in transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#operations):

> The following operations are not allowed in transactions:
>
> Operations that affect the database catalog, such as creating or dropping a collection or an index. For example, a transaction cannot include an insert operation that would result in the creation of a new collection.

You  could:

1. retrieve the version from collection
2. generate an ObjectId to use for new data
3. insert data, associating it with ObjectId generated in step 2
4. update the collection in step 1 to have version = version + 1 and the ObjectId set to the one generated in step 2 using conditional update on version = original version; if the update doesn't match any documents restart from step 1
5. remove old and orphan data

Subsequently, to query you'd need to obtain the ObjectId from the version and query by ObjectId.

No transactions are needed in this implementation.

Comment: This may not solve the problem completely, consider a case where this API gets 100 requests at a time and say, 90 of those are for different records but 10 are for same record. 
in C# world, i can play around with  critical section or DB row level lock or mutex/semaphore.

Comment: If you try to drop & create 100 tables in the same second I have a feeling no relational database will be completely happy with that. I do not recommend performing that many collection creates/drops in MongoDB either.